# POST Request to Heroku in Python - 403 Forbidden

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm learning web scraping and building a simple web app at the moment, and I decided to practice scraping a schedule of classes. Here's a code snippet I'm having trouble with in my application, using Python 2.7.4, Flask, Heroku, BeautifulSoup4, and Requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

url = "https://telebears.berkeley.edu/enrollment-osoc/osc"
code = "26187"
values = dict(_InField1 = "RESTRIC", _InField2 = code, _InField3 = "13D2")
html = requests.post(url, params=values)
soup = Soup(html.content, from_encoding="utf-8")

sp = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "layout-div"})[2]
print sp.text
```

This works great locally. It gives me back the string "Computer Science 61A P 001 LEC:" as expected. However, when I tried to run it on Heroku (using `heroku run bash` and then run `python`), I got back an error,`403 Forbidden`.

Am I missing some settings on Heroku? At first I thought it's the school settings, but then I was wondering why it works locally without any trouble... Any explanation/suggestion would be really appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe the 403 error is coming from a CSRF issue.

Comment: Thanks, so that means that I shouldn't be able to get information on Heroku? I've searched and found this, http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/, but I'm not sure how related it would be to what I'm needing now

Comment: I don't know very well Heroku but I know Django, where a CSRF token should be provided as a hidden field inside your forms. That way Django knows the form is safe to read. I assumed your request was missing this kind of safety from there. What do you mean *when I tried to run it on Heroku* ? Are you trying to fetch a string from an external website with your script located on Heroku ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I deploy my app on heroku but it doesnt do anything (and Chrome Dev Tool says there's a problem in the POST request), so I narrow the problem down, make a small script while inside heroku's shell, and the part I posted above give the error.

Comment: Then I believe your issue is specific to Heroku. There might be indeed some missing settings. You could always contact the Heroku support, sorry I cannot help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, request was working locally but getting blocked on Heroku. It looks like the issue is that some websites block requests coming from Heroku (which on on AWS Servers). To get around this you can send your requests via a proxy server.

There are a bunch of different add-ons in heroku to achieve this, I went with fixie which has a reasonably sized free tier.

To install:

```
heroku addons:create fixie:tricycle
```

Then import into your local environment so you can try locally:

```
heroku config -s | grep FIXIE_URL >> .env
```

then in your python file you just add a couple of lines:

```python
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

proxyDict = {
    "http"  : os.environ.get('FIXIE_URL', ''),
    "https" : os.environ.get('FIXIE_URL', '')
}

url = "https://telebears.berkeley.edu/enrollment-osoc/osc"
code = "26187"
values = dict(_InField1 = "RESTRIC", _InField2 = code, _InField3 = "13D2")
html = requests.post(url, params=values, proxies=proxyDict)
soup = Soup(html.content, from_encoding="utf-8")

sp = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "layout-div"})[2]
print sp.text
```

Docs for Fixie are here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie

Comment: I think this is what's wrong with my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63452311/)   I tried this proxy you mentioned but it did not seem to help in my case